# Moving of list item one up results in broken animation

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I am simply trying to move items in a list using some very basic code & everything works fine, except when I try to move an item to a place just one above it.

It looks as if it first swaps the data of those two rows and then starts the animation to move the row from the original position.

Does anyone have an idea of what could cause this and, more importantly, how to fix it? Thanks!

```
struct ContentView : View {

    @State var zahlen = [1,2,3,4,5]

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(zahlen, id: \.self) { z in
                Text("\(z)")
            }.onMove(perform: self.move)
        }.environment(\.editMode, .constant(.active))
    }

    func move(source: IndexSet, destination: Int) {
        zahlen.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: destination)
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue and currently I think that this is a `SwiftUI` bug, but would be happy to know the solution or workaround

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me using iOS 14.2 this bug does seem to no longer occur.

Answer (score 0):

Its a swift bug this work for me.

```
 struct ContentView : View {

@State var zahlen = [1,2,3,4,5]

var body: some View {
    List {
        ForEach(zahlen, id: \.self.hashValue) //<<-- here it is "hashValue is deprecated as a Hashable requirement." but until the bug is fixed i think we can use it. 
                                             { z in
            Text("\(z)")
        }.onMove(perform: self.move)
    }.environment(\.editMode, .constant(.active))
}

func move(source: IndexSet, destination: Int) {
    zahlen.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: destination)
}
```

}